# Is it possible to have multiple stop codons in one exon?

Tags: molecular-genetics, codon

I would be very happy if someone can help me to find the answers for the following related questions.

1. Can one exon have many stop codons?
2. Can protein synthesis happen, if the stop codon is at the beginning of the exon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An exon can have multiple stop codons but the first codon will terminate the ORF. The remainder of the exon will be a part of the 3'UTR.

However, there are some cases in which stop codon readthrough happens [<sup>[1]</sup>](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/nar/gku608). In these cases an internal stop codon does not terminate the translation and the ribosome reads through it. During this process an aminoacyl-tRNA successfully competes with the release factor. This is quite evident in the case of selenocysteine and pyrollysine- tRNAs which bind to the `UAG` (amber) stop codon in certain organisms <sup>[[2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.febslet.2005.03.004),[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_genetic_code#Amber_codon_suppression)]</sup> (this is also referred to as amber suppression). The exact mechanisms that affect stop codon readthrough are not elucidated but features in the mRNAs are likely to play a role in this. In case of amber suppression, the relative rarity of the `UAG` stop codon and lower concentrations of release factor-1, can be major factors.

I don't know what you mean by "beginning of the exon" but there are short ORFs (< 100 codons) which can code for small peptides [<sup>[4]</sup>](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nrg3520). Small peptide as small as 6 amino acid residues has been reported but most of the known small peptides are ~30-100 residues long.

---

<sub>**References**:

[1] Loughran, Gary, et al. "[Evidence of efficient stop codon readthrough in four mammalian genes.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/nar/gku608)" *Nucleic acids research* 42.14 (2014): 8928-8938. 

[2] Agafonov, Dmitry E., et al. "[Efficient suppression of the amber codon in E. coli in vitro translation system](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.febslet.2005.03.004)." FEBS letters 579.10 (2005): 2156-2160. 

[3] [Wikipedia: Expanded genetic code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_genetic_code#Amber_codon_suppression) 

[4] Andrews, Shea J., and Joseph A. Rothnagel. "[Emerging evidence for functional peptides encoded by short open reading frames.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nrg3520)" *Nature Reviews Genetics* 15.3 (2014): 193-204.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more clarification. In one of the human protein, i am getting three stop codons (UAG, UAA, UGA). However, i am getting more than 80% of UGA in my transcripts. I appreciate if any one educate me, which is the most frequently present stop codon in human transcripts.

Comment: @Krithi.S I have not checked but this is fairly easy to do. Just download all human mRNA sequences from RefSeq/GTF file with CDS annotations and find the stop codons.

Comment: I'm tempted to link articles from the sixties with me being so old. Amber is the most commonly read through stop codon throughout nature.  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0014579305003224 for a modern example of how it's used

Comment: Right that appears to be the mechanism, but it should be noted that it's specific to the Amber stop codon. In bacteria and viruses you can often see doubling or even tripling up of stop codons to prevent Amber readthrough

Comment: @AtlLED Is there readthrough in mammalian/human genes?

Comment: @MattDMo I certainly know of cases in cancers and viruses using host machinery. Off the top of my head I don't know of any endogenous examples in mammals, but one could look. I note the OP makes no mention in the question.

Comment: @AtlLED yeah, I haven't heard of any endogenous examples either, I was just wondering if recent work had come up with anything. Of course, anything goes with tumors/viruses, so that's not surprising.

Comment: @MattDMo Quiet true. But given that when it happens, it's normally only a small portion of actual translation, that I don't think anyone is looking closely enough in the absence of some pathology. I suppose if a bioinforamtics PhD student wants to tackle this, you could look for cases in the human genome where there is an amber followed by another stop codon and see if you find read through on that gene (with 2nd stop oblated). I think it would be hard to get funding on it though. Checking PubMed, I'm pretty sure nobody is looking.

Comment: @AtlLED something for me to do at home in my spare time. Minus the wet work, of course :)

Comment: @MattDMo the linked article (ref#1) talks about readthrough in human genes

Comment: @WYSIWYG My point was that wasn't endogenous. I was thinking a Crisper exp. would be more convincing than transient expression.

Comment: @AtlLED As long as the entire cDNA is cloned and expressed there should not be a great difference, unless the plasmid expresses too many mRNA copies in which case there might be concentration dependent effects. I agree that working on an endogenous system is better. By CRISPR experiment you mean mutate one of the stop codons?

Comment: @WYSIWYG That's exactly what I mean.  The transfection experiment was a good 1st step, but I have a hard time imagining that cDNA under CMV or PGK promotion will not confound studying read-through (over expression or lenti incorporation as done in ref 1).  I think oblating the second stop codon in the genome would be the ideal way to look at this.  Also, we should probably move to chat after this, because I think we're diverging from the question.

Comment: @MattDMo absolutely. Not only is there "abnormal" readthrough, you also have selenoproteins where the amber codon codes for a *bona fide* aminoacid, Sec.